# SharePoint webpart with button to auto-login to 3rd party website

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, web-parts

I have been tasked with creating a SharePoint 2007 webpart that logs the user directly into our website (which uses forms authentication). Most likely the username and password will be same in the SharePoint account as in our website.

Ideally we would like it to be fully integrated in that the webpart looks up the SP login & password, somehow encodes that using SHA1, MD5 or similar encryption, then passes that along to our login page on the query string. However given we have little experience with SharePoint, and that it's probably impossible to programmatically access the SP username/password from a webpart we realize this isn't very likely to be possible and if so would probably require a lot of development time.

Another option would be to load a login form from the website within an iframe in the webpart, which would show the login & password first but store a "remember me" cookie after the first login, and on each subsequent load display just a button that logs them in directly using the cookie.

Has anyone done something similar before? I'm in over my head, any guidance would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

A good login system doesn't allow retrieval of passwords at all. (Forgot your password? Prove you're you and we'll reset it, send it to you, and force you to change it to something we can't see once you're back.) This way you CYA against both Angry IT Admin Guy back-dooring his way into other user accounts when he's disgruntled over coffee pot politics as well as a potential attack vector for the Internet at large to exploit.

The cookie idea is plausible. Depending on your SharePoint/other website configuration you may be able to federate your logins to a single authentication provider (using ADFS, Passport, OpenID, etc.), which would be a more elegant solution, but may not be feasible in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SPS 2010 and your other website is based on .NET, then [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) would be a option.